# Carrierwave two cache files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, jquery-file-upload

I'm using carrierwave with jquery fileupload to upload sound files.
I change the cache directory but I don't get why it creates it twice.
Here my sound_uploader.rb:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'carrierwave/processing/mime_types'

class SoundUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  store :file
  after  :cache, :after_cache
  before :store, :before_store
  after  :store, :after_store


  def after_cache(file)
    puts 'AFTER CACHE'
  end
  def before_store(file)
    puts 'BEFORE STORE'
  end
  def after_store(file)
    puts 'AFTER STORE'
  end

  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

  def store_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/uploads/files/#{model.user_id}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

It returns me in my console:

```
AFTER CACHE
AFTER CACHE
BEFORE STORE
AFTER STORE
```

Plus it creates 2 cache folder with different cache_id and i can't remove the 1st cache file.

EDIT: I puts in my SoundController

```
def create
puts 'HELLO WORLD!'
...
end
```

And i noticed the result is:

```
AFTER CACHE
HELLO WORLD!
AFTER CACHE
BEFORE STORE
AFTER STORE
```

This mean that it puts into cache my file before actually created my sound.
I still didn't get why but it might be a clue to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you added load_and_authorize_resource to your controller, you probably forgot to remove the line

`@sound = Sound.new(params[:sound])`

from the create action, which causes the resource to be loaded twice. That makes Carrierwave to move/copy the file to the cache twice as well.

Otherwise your code wouldn't be working after avoiding load_and_authorize_resource for create action.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the line responsable of my problem.
I'll investigate more about the reason and edit my post after that but the problem where coming from CanCan gem

```
class SoundsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  ...
end
```

I change by:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:create]
```